# Infinity loop using useState with useEffect in React

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I want to increase the state [second] = [second + 1] after every second.

```
const [second,setSecond] = useState(0);
useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setSecond(second+1)
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);
```

But it seems that an infinity loop occurs, the [second] just increases once, from 0 to 1, and it stops running.

I changed my code from

```
setSecond(second+1)
```

to

```
setSecond((second) => {return second+1})
```

And this one runs without problem:

```
const [second,setSecond] = useState(0);
useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setSecond((second) => {return second+1})
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);
```

Seriously, I still don't get it clearly. Can anybody explain to me why? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code, I think the issue is with the value of second being bound to 0.

```
const [second,setSecond] = useState(0);
useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setSecond(second+1)
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);
```

Here when your component mounts, the useEffect is executed. At that time you are creating a function and passing it to setInterval. This function will use the value of `second` at the time of creation (which equals 0). So everytime when the setInterval runs, it is executing `setSecond(0+1)` which always equals 1.

The correct way that you have mentioned works because you're giving it a function which gets passed into it the current value of state everytime it is executed.

Answer (score 1):

Ciao, the 2 ways you are using to set `second` are different.

This way:

```
setSecond(second+1)
```

does not consider the previuos value of `second`. It just try to increment second by 1 by reading current value of `second`. Considering that `setSecond` is async, on next `setInterval` is not guaranteed that `second` will be updated by the previous `setSecond`. So in this way you could have glitch.

This way:

```
setSecond((second) => {return second+1})
```

is the correct one. Here you are considering the previuos value of `second` (by using arrow function). So in this case, `second` will be correctly update.

You could make a test: Take a button and on onclick function try to write:

```
setSecond(second+1)
setSecond(second+1)
```

you will see that `second` will be incremented by 1 (and not by 2 as expected).

Now modify your code like this:

```
setSecond((second) => {return second+1})
setSecond((second) => {return second+1})
```

you will see that `second` will be incremented by 2!

This happends because Hooks are async.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help you :)